# Hide navbar programatically in react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

I'm using [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux).

I'm aware one can show/hide the navbar per scene by using `hideNavbar` on the respective scene like so:

```
const scenes = Actions.create(
    <Scene key="root">
        <Scene key="main" component={mainComponent} initial={true} hideNavBar={true}/>
        <Scene key="secondary" component={secondaryComponent} hideNavBar={false} />
    </Scene>
);
```

I need to toggle the navbar on/off dynamically depending on the state of the current Scene.

The readme says:

> Highly Customizable Navigation Bar - Show/hide the navbar depending on Scene **or even the state of a Scene** (e.g. Edit/Save navbar for edit mode).

I didn't find any detailed instructions for that though. Can anyone please advise or provide a link to an example?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Readme](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/README.md):

> `Actions.refresh(PARAMS)` will update the properties of the current
>   screen.

To update mounted scene programmatically, you can simply do:

```
Actions.refresh({key: 'yourSceneKey', hideNavBar: true});
```

Feel free to put any other props there, for example you can also change the title of your scene with this refresh function.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks! (I had actually tried something similar before posting the question but something wasn't working)

Comment: Glad it helped!